# Can I monitor a Logic App application with Azure App Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to monitor a Logic App application with Azure App Insights ?

Comment: Hi Karthik, may I know more details of your requirements ? Maybe I can provide some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, Unfortunately, there is no built-in support for Azure Logic Apps. One workaround you can do is to create an Azure Function to log events in your Azure Function subscription, and adding those actions in the key places you want to instrument for your logic app.